# How to make maschek image map tinymce plugin works for tinymce 4

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce-4

I try to looking for tinymce plugin image map. Lucky, I found maschek image map URL : https://github.com/maschek/imgmap

But there was a problem. This image map plugin is used for tinymce 3 not for tinymce 4. I have tried to using plugin compatx3. But it didn't worked.

There is several errors appears on console:

Deprecated TinyMCE API call: .onNodeChange.add(..)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'popup_css' of undefined
popup.html:94 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

here is the screenshoot what shows in browser

[image: plugin maschek image map views in tinymce 4 editor]

how do I to put this plugin to tinymce 4 editor correctly and works?

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but:
The plugin needs to be ported to tinyMCE4. Someone did.
Check this link: https://github.com/Gagaro/tinymce-imgmap.

Hope this helps.